# How to make Textchanged Listener in Edit text in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I have two fields: mobile and pass. When a user enters the mobile number, it checks if the mobile number is of ten digit or not. If not, then it should show an error message in the respective field. But here when the app opens, it shows error in the respective fields. How can I solve this problem?

here is code:-

```
private TextWatcher m_oTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {// making object of TextWathcher class
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {// when text change in Edit tEXT

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkFieldsForEmpty();// CHECK LOGIN BUTTON DISABLED AND ENABED
    }
};
/*This Broadcast receiver will listen network state accordingly
which enable or disable create an account button*/
private final BroadcastReceiver m_oOtpReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {// creating broadcast to receive otp sent by server from Inbox...
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {// on receive method to read OTP sent by server
        checkFieldsForEmpty();// check whether edit text is empty or not

    }
};/*This method check Edit text is empty or not*/
public void checkFieldsForEmpty() {// this method check Edit text is empty or not

    s_szMobileNumber = m_InputMobile.getText().toString().trim();// get mobile number from edit Text
    s_szPassword = m_InputPassword.getText().toString().trim();// get password from edit text

    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
        // if mobile number and password are Emoty
        if (s_szMobileNumber!= null && s_szMobileNumber.length()>7 && s_szMobileNumber.length()<15) {// check if mobile and password is empty ..
            if (s_szPassword.length()>=4&&s_szPassword.length()<=8) {
                m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(true);// make Login button disabled

                m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
                m_LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// onclick listener on Login Button
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        postLoginDataToServer();

                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                m_InputPassword.setError("Password must be between 4 to 8 characters long");
                m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);// make login button enabled
                m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button
            }

        } else {
            m_InputMobile.setError("Mobile number must be between 7 to 15 characters long");
            m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);// make login button enabled
            m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button

        }

    } else {
        try {
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No Internet Connection Available", getApplicationContext());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);
        m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your `BroadReceiver` is called first time `m_oOtpReceiver` that is checking network state. and for first time your edit text has no value so length is 0 and it will meet the condition that 0 is not greater that 7 so it will display error first time .

***Solution :***

If method is called from `BroadcastReceiver` you dont have to check validation so skip that part.

```
public void checkFieldsForEmpty(boolean fromBroadcast) {// this method check Edit text is empty or not

    s_szMobileNumber = m_InputMobile.getText().toString().trim();// get mobile number from edit Text
    s_szPassword = m_InputPassword.getText().toString().trim();// get password from edit text

    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {

           if(!fromBroadcast){
                  // check validation
               }
           else{
                  // no need to check validation
             }
        }
```

from textwatcher

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkFieldsForEmpty(false);// CHECK LOGIN BUTTON DISABLED AND ENABED
    }
```

from broadcast receiver

```
 checkFieldsForEmpty(true);
```

or you can check whether to display error message.

```
   if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
            // if mobile number and password are Emoty
            if (s_szMobileNumber!= null && s_szMobileNumber.length()>7 && s_szMobileNumber.length()<15) {// check if mobile and password is empty ..
                if (s_szPassword.length()>=4&&s_szPassword.length()<=8) {
                    m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(true);// make Login button disabled

                    m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 80, 147));// set background color on eabled
                    m_LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// onclick listener on Login Button
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            postLoginDataToServer();

                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
     if(!fromBroadcast){

                    m_InputPassword.setError("Password must be between 4 to 8 characters long");
}
                    m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);// make login button enabled
                    m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button
                }

            } else {
     if(!fromBroadcast){
                m_InputMobile.setError("Mobile number must be between 7 to 15 characters long");
    }
                m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);// make login button enabled
                m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button

            }

        } else {
            try {
                CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No Internet Connection Available", getApplicationContext());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m_LoginBtn.setEnabled(false);
            m_LoginBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
        }
```

Comment: but my scenario is that

Comment: The login/create an account button should get enabled when internet is available and disabled when internet is not available, this should be done in real time, currently it seems like internet availability is being checked on key press event. Now, considering two scenario

Comment: 1. We enter all the details and then enable the internet.
Expected Result:login/create an account button should be enabled.
Actual Result: login/create an account button remains disabled.

Comment: 2. Internet is available, We enter all the required details, the button gets enabled. Now, if the internet gets disabled
Expected Result: Button should be disabled
Actual Result: Button remains enabled

Comment: in that case you can check if it is from internet check dont display error message and if not than display it . fair?

Comment: check this  @Nitin

Comment: if I show error on edit text focus change the how can I

Comment: please tell me I am on my success

Comment: check all the condition and modify code that will meet all your scenario.